# how do you get a list of checkboxes from asp.net code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I'm sure this is an easy problem, but i can't think of a way (other than using javascript to force a postback) to get a list of checkboxes in the asp.net code behind.

each checkbox is in a seperate custom control so i can't use a checkboxlist.

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? In what sense are they a 'list' of checkboxes if each is in a separate custom control?

Comment: Are these WebControls or HTML Controls?

Comment: because there are several of these custom controls. and i want to loop through them to see which ones are clicked after a button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

If you have a usercontrol with N number of checkboxes, you need to expose a public property holding the collection of ids, controls...whatever it is that you need access to from the parent container.

Comment: +1 - agreed, modify the custom control's interface to either expose the checkbox's id, the checkbox itself, or the state that Checkbox.Checked represents.

Comment: You could simply do a foreach on the controls collection of the UserControl, iterating through and checking for checkboxes using the is.

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively traverse the hierarchy of the controls on a Page and just get the controls that are CheckBoxes

In your page you can declare a member that will be used to store the checkboxes:

```
private List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
```

Using a recursive method you can traverse the controls structure:

```
public void TraverseHierarchy(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = c as CheckBox;
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            checkBoxes.Add(checkBox);
        }
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            TraverseHierarchy(c.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can call this by providing the controls collection of the Page:

```
TraverseHierarchy(Page.Controls);
```

However a problem with the above code is that there are certain controls that inherit from the CheckBox control. Like the `RadioButton` for instance. So that control will also be matched present in your collection because the `as` is valid.

What you could do is either do further filtering based on a certain property of your checkboxes. For instance if your `ID` naming is consistent across your checkboxes you can also check that the ID property starts with a specific prefix:

```
public void TraverseHierarchy(ControlCollection controls)
{
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = c as CheckBox;
        if (checkBox != null)
        {
            if (checkBox.ID.StartsWith("cb"))
            {
                checkBoxes.Add(checkBox);
            }
        }
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            TraverseHierarchy(c.Controls);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could eliminate the controls that extend the CheckBox by using the `is` operator but that will be an extra hit on performance and quite an ugly solution.